# android studio and appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

Assuming I'm making a new android project from scratch that targets API 15-21, do I really need the `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` in `build.gradle`?

Can I remove it and not be worried about it?

Comment: If you want to use `AppCompat` of course. What is your concern here?

Comment: Are you using any Material Design features that will need to be compatible with API < 21?  If so, then you should include appcompat.

Comment: See my comment to @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I really need the "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'" in build.gradle?

If you want a Material Design-styled action bar on API Level 7-20 (or, in your case, 15-20), then yes. Otherwise, for a `minSdkVersion` of 15, usually you do not need it.

> Can I remove it and not be worried about it?

You can remove it, but you may need to adjust Java classes (e.g., have your activities directly inherit from `Activity`, not from `ActionBarActivity`), menu resources (use `android:` prefixes for everything, not `app:` prefixes), and themes (make sure they do not inherit from `Theme.AppCompat`). Basically, anything in the project that depends upon `appcomat-v7` needs to be adjust to no longer depend upon stuff in `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: I imported my project from eclipse and had no problem so now I do need to do conversions (the opposite of what you mentioned) because of appcompat so I was wondering if I actually need it or not. I don't know if I need actionbaractivity and such, I have one activity and several fragments.

Comment: @Amos: I cannot really explain it any more simply than I did. Do you want an action bar that has the Material Design look, on devices older than Android 5.0? If yes, use `appcompat-v7`. If not, you do not need `appcompat-v7`.